# Max RAM: CPU vs Motherboard

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

Looking to put together a cheap(er) server/workstation for doing some big statistical analysis. Right now, it's running on a machine with 16gb and we're using 40gb of swap. So I want to maximize available RAM. The software is custom and old, and we don't have the resources to multi-thread it. So we're limited to 1 cpu (no dual/quad socket motherboards).

Anyway, looking at ordering an intel i7 3930K and it says on intel's site that it only supports 32GB. However most LGA 2011 motherboards say they support up to 64GB. And searching I see all sorts of people running all sorts of large amounts of ram - some claiming 256gb!

But even with a quad socket MB, 32GB per socket would limit you to 128GB.

So basically, how can I maximize my RAM potential on a cheaper server.

**What happens if I put 64gb in a motherboard that supports it, but the CPU only lists 32gb. I'm assuming it just doesn't recognize the other 32gb?**

Thanks.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that it's currently very difficult to find 8GB unbuffered DIMMs like most boards require anyway.  Since most of these boards have 8 DIMM slots, 8x4=32.  That's where a lot of it comes from.  This is the same deal with LGA1155 - they all say they support 32GB but practically it's almost impossible to put more than 16GB in them.

Comment: Well right now Newegg has several 32 (4x8gb) quad channel kits. So it would be easy to get 64gb into an X79 mobo. But it doesn't seem like it matters. I just keep hearing speculation, and it doesn't seem like anyone really has a definitive answer.

Comment: That must have changed pretty recently then.  There were NONE available anywhere last time I looked.